# Google Polymer: Where is the localstorage?

Tags: polymer

When we use core-localstorage

```html
<core-localstorage name="my-app-storage" value="{{value}}"></core-localstorage>
```

where it actually store the data? In some file on the HDD? What is the path?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_storage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LocalStorage is one of some ways you can store data in the client end in the Hard-drive, different browsers use different locations to save this file.
LocalStraoge makes use of JSON to store information worth up to 10MB(Might differ from browsers).

Usually, storing and retrieving from Local-storage is done through JavaScript but Polymer team has made a custom element you can use to make this process more Declarative.

Using the `core-localstorage` element:

```
<core-localstorage name="HOW YOU ACCESS THIS DATA" value="{{THE ACTUAL DATA YOU WANT TO STORE}}"></core-localstorage>
```

`name` attribute is how you access this data, every peice of data you store has to have a name with which you can set or get it's value through.

`value` attribute is the actual data you want to store, it can be an array, object, number or a string.

More documentations about `core-localstorage` and `localstorage` can be found at:
https://www.polymer-project.org/0.5/docs/elements/core-localstorage.html
http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html